# Projecting a matrix unto a uncorrelated matrix

Tags: regression

If $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon|Z] = 0,\ Var[\epsilon|Z] = \sigma^2I$, 
and $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon|X] \ne 0 $

then is the following true?

$\mathbb{E}[\epsilon|Z(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^TX] = 0$, $Var[\epsilon|Z(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^TX] = \sigma^2I$

Assuming $Z$ and $X$ are full col rank.

$Z_{(n\times m)}$ and $X_{(n\times k)}$ are random matrices, and $\epsilon_{k\times 1}$ is a random vector. $ m \ge k$

$Z$ is highly correlated with $X$. Essentially $Z$ is the instrumental variable to $X$.

Comment: Could you provide more information, like is there any relation between' Z' & 'X'?

Comment: Hint: consider the possibility $Z(Z^\prime Z)^{-1}Z^\prime X=X.$

Comment: @whuber I don't think that should be a possibility since $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon|Z] \implies \mathbb{E}[Z\epsilon] = 0$ which will mean that the projected matrix will be that also? I need some reference material for this.

Comment: @Nizam, the assumption is that $X$ and $Z$ are highly correlated i.e $Z$ is an instrumental variable

Comment: Because you haven't made any assumptions about $X$ and $Z$ in your question--you haven't even specified whether they are random variables or not--the possibility I mentioned is certainly plausible.  For instance, take $Z$ to be a constant vector. As a counterexample, it answers your question, at least in the vague and general form in which it is stated.  If you need to include more information, as suggested by your comments, then please edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's a counterexample.**  Let $Z$ be a $1\times 1$ random matrix (or a constant, for that matter) with $\Pr(Z=0)=0$ and $\epsilon$ a zero-mean random variable independent of $Z.$  Suppose as in the question that $X$ is a random variable with $E[\epsilon\mid X] \ne 0.$ Assuming what you like about the correlation between $X$ and $Z,$ it is always the case that

$$E[\epsilon\mid Z (Z^\prime Z)^{-1} Z^\prime X] = E[\epsilon\mid X] \ne 0.$$

The existence of this counterexample is not due to the simplicity of the situation: similar counterexamples exist for $n\times m$ matrices $Z$ (random or not); they're just a little more complicated to compute.